# Can I call bind() and then connect() on same socket descriptor?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, network-programming

Just a curious question about networking socket programming in a Windows Application with C/C++:

How can I tell the `connect()` function to use a particular source IP and source port values?

- After a socket is created, application calls `connect()` to remote IP and port by using the `sockaddr` structure.
- the `connect()` function internally selects the source IP and port for the connection.

Rather than the system deciding the source IP and/or port for the `connect()`, let that be the application's responsibility to decide which source IP and/or port to bind to.

Comment: ["If socket s, is unbound, unique values are assigned to the local association by the system, and the socket is marked as bound."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect)

Comment: You need to call `bind` if you want to specify which interface/port combination to use.

Comment: "*Let that be applications responsibility to decide on source port or IP to bind to*" -- note that although there may indeed be reasons for taking this approach with a socket you are going to `connect()`, they are at best rare.  The source port for such a connection is not normally significant at the application level, and there are rarely many options for the source IP (unless the machine is connecting to itself).

Answer (score 4):

> How can I tell the connect() function to use a particular source IP and source port values?

Use the socket library's `bind()` function for that.  Yes, you can call `bind()` before `connect()` for an outgoing socket.  That is a perfectly legitimate operation for both UDP and TCP sockets.

Answer (score 4):

`bind()` requests port that is not in use so it can claim it and become a server, while `connect()` wants a port that is already in use, so it can connect to it and talk to the server.

As user *stark* said, you need to call `bind` if you want to specify which interface/port combination to use, although if you want next call to bind it to a random available port number, you can opt out from `bind()` call because client doesn't necessarily has to have a fixed port number.

It is possible to ask the kernel to select a specific port before calling `connect()`, but if I may ask - why you wouldn't want to kernel to allocate source ports, as far as I know it's not best practice.

Comment: A couple of use cases off the top of my head: It is possible to bind a socket to an interface without binding to a port (here the port will be selected when connect is called.). Also, in P2P networking, explicit port allocation is needed before connect is called to enable NAT traversal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  **Indeed there's a reason to do that:**  In case your routing policy makes your connection to be established from an IP address which is not the one you want to use, you can force in a multihomed/routing host a specific IP address as source by means of `bind(2)` system call.  Another use is to specify a fixed source port for the connection, but this is not as usual as the previous case.

But beware: you can select only one of the already configured IP addresses you have, not any address you can imagine.